# Constant expression required error when assigning the method return type to case

Tags: java, switch-statement

I have written a constant file.

```
public interface IConstants {

    int SOME_CONSTANT = 6;
}
```

I've written a wrapper method to access "SOME_CONSTANT" variable in ConstantWrapper file

```
public class ConstantWrapper {

   static ConstantWrapper mConstantWrapper = null;

    private ConstantWrapper(){

    }

    public static ConstantWrapper getInstance(){
        if(mConstantWrapper == null)
            mConstantWrapper = new ConstantWrapper();

        return mConstantWrapper;
    }

    public int getSomeConstantValue(){
        return IConstants.SOME_CONSTANT;
    }
}
```

Now, i want to access the wrapper method in switch case statement but i get error "constant expression required". How to resolve this?

```
public class DemoClass{

private void checkSwitchCases(int value) {
        

        switch (value){
            case ConstantWrapper.getInstance().getSomeConstantValue(): // I get the error "constant expression required" in this line
                System.out.println("Case 6");
                break;

            case 8:
                System.out.println("Case 8");
                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("Case default");
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: for the compiler, that can be any value, and can change. what would the compiler have to do, for instance, if that value were 8 ?

Comment: that's just an example, i just want to get rid of this error in the first case statement

Comment: That  `ConstantWrapper.getInstance().getSomeConstantValue():` returns a constant value _today_ is no guarantee that it will _tomorrow_, so the Java compiler has to compile `DemoClass` as if it has no idea what `ConstantWrapper.getInstance().getSomeConstantValue():` returns.  But if _you_ happen to know that it will always return `IConstants.SOME_CONSTANT`, you should just write `case IConstants.SOME_CONSTANT:` in your `switch`.  And if you can't do that, you'll have to change the switch into an `if` cascade.

Comment: @user2511004 it isn't an error, and you can't (and shouldn't) get rid of it

Answer (score 1):

You're applying all sorts of anti-patterns here. It looks like you have a problem (here: I have some constants I want to manage) and decided on a solution to your problem (an interface + a class you erroneously call a 'wrapper'), and are now asking further questions about issues you've run into implementing your solution. But, it's not a good solution, so let's go back to the original problem.

> I have written a constant file

Shoving a bunch of constants into an interface used to be common, but now that we have enums are star imports, this is no longer the recommended way to do this. Just put your constants where-ever they are most relevant (unlikely to be an interface, but if you must, okay) - and use `import static com.foo.ThatType.*;` in a class that wants to use them. Do not `implements` your `IConstants` anywhere - the type hierarchy of your classes is public information that ought to say something about structure, and `IConstants` is meaningless, which is why that's bad style.

> `IConstants`

this hungarian notation variant is not recommended. Your IDE is perfectly capable of informing you if some type is an interface or class if you find that information relevant. You shouldn't write code as if this is relevant in the first place: Two excellent reasons for why the `IName` thing is an anti-pattern.

> `class ConstantWrapper`

What purpose does this serve? You've signed yourself up to a ton of work, to keep that ConstantWrapper class maintained. The only real benefit I can surmise is that you have the option of plugging in an alternate implementation, but that would imply these constants aren't, in fact, constant in the first place, and thus the error you get is correct, and the solution is not to use a `switch` at all, and in general stop using the term 'constant'. It's a bad idea to call a thing with a bunch of corners on it 'a circle'. Naming is hard, but important.

> `public static ConstantWrapper getInstance()`

You aren't applying double locking, which means you can have 2 or more instances of ConstantWrapper. If you must dynamically load a class, you should rely on the classloader. However, there is absolutely no point whatsoever in using a `getInstance` method that actually initializes: java does not load all classes on boot; it merely loads a class on first use. Given that 'first use' of `ConstantWrapper` is going to be `.getInstance()`, java will **already** init things exactly when you want them to. Therefore:

1. ConstantWrapper shouldn't exist at all.
2. If you somehow must have it for a reason not stated in your question, this is how to do it:

```
public class ConstantWrapper {
    private static final ConstantWrapper INSTANCE = new ConstantWrapper();
    public static ConstantWrapper getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

This accomplishes exactly what you want (namely, that there is only ever 1 instance, and that this instance is not initialized until it is needed), but now with less code, and with no bugs.

> Constant expression required error

A method invocation **cannot be a constant expression** period. Source: Java Language Specification.

a static and final field that is initialised as it is declared, whose type is primitive or a String, and isn't `null` is a constant expression if the initialising expression is constant. That's where it ends. So, this works:

```
class Example {
    public static final int FOO = 5;
}

class Foo {
    {
        switch (value) {
            case Example.FOO: // allowed; this is a constant expression
            case 10: // allowed; this is constant too
        }
    }
}
```

even something like `static final int A = 5, B = 10, C = A + B;` is allowed (`C` is also constant here, because the compiler can figure that out at compile time), but the compiler won't go particularly far.

There is no way to make a method invocation count as a constant expression, and there is no way to tell `switch` to accept non-constant expressions.